# Installing psycopg2 failed with python 3.2 but not with 3.4

Tags: postgresql, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, build-process

First of all, I am sorry for asking a question that was asked million times, however, I couldn't resolve my issue.

TL;DR:
`psycopg2` builds in Python3.4 virtualenv, but not in Python3.2; suspected dev packages missing, where can I get dev packages for old python releases?

Long story:
I should be writing code for Python3.2 using django with PostgreSQL database engine.

Ubuntu 15.04 by default ships with Python3.4 so I have build Python3.2 from source:

```
$ python3.2 --version
Python 3.2.6
```

`virtualenv` is created so:

```
myproject $ virtualenv -p python3.2 venv
New python executable in venv/bin/python3.2
Also creating executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
```

Installing requirements:

```
myproject $ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)myproject $ pip install psycopg2
```

The output log can be found in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/AJBTbyGZ).

What I have read there:

- GCC finishes whatever its doing without error messages; last non-error reporting line is

`running install_lib`

- then it fails with

`Command /home/julka/LP/myproject/venv/bin/python3.2 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-cbu7a3/psycopg2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-cyu65o-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/julka/LP/myproject/venv/include/site/python3.2 failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-cbu7a3/psycopg2`

where it was compiling some lib.

Building with `Python3.4`

```
julka@Pyragas-vo2:~/L1P/myproject$ virtualenv -p python3.4 venv
Running virtualenv with interpreter /usr/bin/python3.4
Using base prefix '/usr'
New python executable in venv/bin/python3.4
Also creating executable in venv/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.
julka@Pyragas-vo2:~/LP/myproject$ source venv/bin/activate
(venv)julka@Pyragas-vo2:~/LP/myproject$ pip install psycopg2 --vv > psycopg2.log
Successfully installed psycopg2
Cleaning up...
(venv)julka@Pyragas-vo2:~/LP/myproject$
```

Successful installation. I have put the log in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/fvBThV9u).

Maybe I'm missing some kind of development files for python3.2, what do i need to check this out?

Comment: The output logs in /tmp/pip-build-cbu7a3/psycopg2 will be useful for debugging this issue. Could you please add it to your question?

Comment: `ls /tmp` outputs the same before and after `pip install psycopg2` with any virtualenv activated and none of the entries resembles log. There are `pip_delete_this_directory.txt` though.